# Rails error, unexpected tSYMBEG, when creating a database for products order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, syntax

I am trying to create a simple database in rails to store the user and the product id's.

I get this error:

```
from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.3 :015 > rails g migration create_orders user_id :integer :index product_id :integer :index total :float
SyntaxError: (irb):15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
...reate_orders user_id :integer :index product_id :integer :in...
...                               ^
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/TXII/Desktop/nameofapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/TXII/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TXII/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/TXII/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.3 :016 > rails g migration create_orders user_id:integer:index product_id:integer:index total:float
```

when I try to run this

```
rails g migration create_orders user_id:integer:index product_id:integer:index total:float
```

Has someone know what I am doing wrong here, I cannot figure where the problem is.

Comment: Well, what's the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Also you need to paste the code that is failing...

Comment: I have updated the code and the full message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run that command inside the rails console (or irb), whereas it's supposed to be run from your shell (e.g. bash)